# Check whether FTP upload is successful or not using batch?

Tags: batch, ftp, batch-file

I am running below code in my `ftpUpload.bat`. If file is not uploaded to FTP server it should print "FTP upload is failed" but I am getting "FTP upload is successful" for both cases. What change I need to do in batch file to achieve the correct output

```
@ECHO OFF    
SET ReturnCode="0"
SET EncryptFilePath=%1
SET ReturnCode=0
::Echo Step4 :  Upload Encrypted file in FTP server is started
    @Echo open 104.213.13.281 21>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    @Echo Dev>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    @Echo MyDev>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    @echo binary>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    @echo cd inbound\development\extracts\yxd0>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    @echo put %EncryptFilePath%>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    @echo quit>>C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    ftp -i -s:"C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt" && (
    echo FTP upload is successful
    DEL C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
    ) || (
    echo FTP upload is failed
    echo ReturnCode="1"
    DEL C:\Case360_EAR_Tool\%FileName%.txt
exit
    )
echo %ReturnCode%
exit
```

Comment: Have you read [How do I check the outcome of a ftp script with a bat file?](http://superuser.com/a/503323/376602)

Comment: @JosefZ The response you've linked is all wrong.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry, it links to a [Shez's double upvoted  answer](http://superuser.com/users/172314/shez?tab=topactivity) and works for me:). A link to the OQ: http://superuser.com/questions/98903

Comment: @JosefZ : not working for me.. :(

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ˙8.1˙ if this matters. Truly, I didn't try that answer validity; my only aim was to give notice to a very similar question that seems to be answered already...  ^Z

Comment: @MartinPrikryl my misunderstanding in translation, sorry: I thought your _response you've linked is all wrong_ comment applies to the **link** I have provided, not to any _solution_ covered with...

Comment: @JosefZ OK, all clear then :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there's a reliable way to do this with Windows `ftp.exe`.

It won't report the result via exit code. It always returns 0, even on error.

All you can do is to parse the `ftp.exe` output. But that's a rather dirty approach. Note that the `ftp.exe` won't even separate errors into an error output, is outputs everything to a standard output.

---

You should better use a 3rd-party FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) you can use:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "cd inbound/development/extracts/yxd0" ^ 
    "put %EncryptFilePath%" ^
    "exit" && (
    echo FTP upload is successful
) || (
    echo FTP upload is failed
    exit
)
```

Where `ftp://user:password@example.com/` would be `ftp://Dev:MyDev@104.213.13.281/`

See also [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP FTP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: is it possible without using WinSCP?

Comment: What do you mean by "without WinSCP?". You can use any other serious command-line FTP client. But as I wrote, the only way to do it with `ftp.exe` is by parsing its output for errors.